# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activemodel

Trying to upgrade to rails 5.2.2. Blew away my gem lock file, and then did a 'bundle install' Lot of dependancy errors, but this is the first error and one i really dont understand:

```
  Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 5.2.2) was resolved to 5.2.2, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.2.2)

    web-console (~> 3.7.0) was resolved to 3.7.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
```

It looks to me that activemodel 5.2.2 is greater than 5.0 and should satisfy the web-console dependency. What am i missing?

Comment: Last I checked 5.2.2 was >= 5.0, but I guess Bundler sees this differently. Can you bump the version of `web-console`? Usually just have `gem 'web-console'` without a version specifier and it figures it out.

Comment: Ok, just did that, it chose web-console 2.3.0 which wants activemodel >= 4.0,but still give the same error otherwise.

Comment: That seems like a step backwards. [Latest version is 4.0.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/web-console).

Comment: Yea, I think i have a lead, i was on bundler 2.0.2 and updated to 2.1.4. Most of the errors vanished including that one. Now i have one last dependency issue with html5shiv-js-rails and railties, but that one the error at least makes sense, him5shiv is looking for railties < 5.1 and >= 4.0, but rails wants 5.2.3.rc1.

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a tangled web of dependencies, but you're on the right track if you're getting ahead like that. Hard to say for sure what's causing this without being able to reproduce it.

Comment: Ended up not needing html5shiv, so i just removed it, problem solved, thanks for hearing me out.

Comment: Nailed it. That's what matters!

Answer (score 1):

In the end i upgraded form bundler 2.0.2 to 2.1.4. That resolved the problem.